# Does having a dependency on interface rather than concrete class reduce compile time in Java if changes are made to concrete class?

Tags: java

I was reading "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers and in one subtopic "Breaking Dependencies", it is mentioned that if a class depends on an interface, then if changes are done to the concrete implementation, the original dependent class doesn't have to be compiled again because you don't directly depend on the implementation.

Chapter of Book for reference : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/working-effectively-with/0131177052/ch07.html

I agree with this, but is there a significant difference in compilation time observed with this change in Java or is this more relevant in context of C++?

I read about the PIMPL pattern or bridge pattern in C++ that is used to provide compile time optimization but is the same thing possible in JAVA as well, or does the java compiler does this optimization by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen compile time as a design consideration in Java ( worked with Java since v 1).  Specifically to your question, the language spec provides no guranteess in this regard. It may change from version to version and implementation to implementation.

Outside of javac, a build system may do the sensible thing, see for example : https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance

**Edit**: Just double checked, `javac` recompiles a source **even if did not change**:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17

$ javac *.java && ls -l A.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr usr 143 Oct 14 20:07 A.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr usr  59 Oct 14 19:57 A.java
```

After waiting a minute...

```
$ javac *.java && ls -l A.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr usr 143 Oct 14 20:08 A.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usr usr  59 Oct 14 19:57 A.java
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no significant difference. The majority of compile time is parsing, and that is not affected at all by this.

The point is this: Given file 'MySource.java', containing some type MySource, if any parent type of MySource is redefined, you really should recompile this class. You don't have to, and java will try its best, but now you can create crazy scenarios (for example, if you update the parent type to add a new abstract method, as in, a method that must be implemented, now you still have a child type that doesn't. You get runtime Errors thrown when you try to mix these classes produced by different compile runs).

The point of using an interface is to avoid it: Have a supertype which did not change at all (nobody touched the interface definition whatsoever) even if the concrete implementation did change.

You'd think that means: Hey, great, now I don't even have to recompile this file. But that's not really relevant; java compilation times are extremely fast compared to C (massive projects in a matter of a few seconds), and it is quite hard to have a build system that is smart enough to realize that recompilation is not needed in such a case. No; the point is a bit of self control: If you have a split project where the interface/parent class is in source repo A, and the child class is in B, things are just gonna break: Unless A and B are maintained by the same person and rebuilt at the same time, you have a problem.

So, the point is: You have 'public API', as in, types which you decree shall not be changed unless you have a really good reason to do so. Make interfaces to be more clear on exactly which bits will not change. This gives the authors of source repo A the freedom to change the (not public/exported) implementation class, so long as they don't mess with the interface, without having to go call the fine folk over at source repo B and tell them: Uh, sorry, we changed things, you have to do a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the concrete class, only the concrete class and its callers need to be recompiled. If you have an interface, and people are calling the interface instead of the concrete class, then they don't count as callers to the concrete class and don't need to be recompiled. This is the only way in which interfaces help reduce compile times, AFAICT.

Every implementation of Java that has type-wise optimization of interfaces defers that optimization to the runtime (HotSpot) optimizer: for more information, the term you're looking for there is "specialization". The Java compilers themselves (ie: the Java => bytecode compilers) actually do surprisingly little optimization, and it is hamstrung because it cannot reason about the code at runtime (cf: Haskell's compiler). This is because you can have dynamic code loading: the set of possible implementations of the interface can be changed at runtime by classpath modifications and reflection.